# Empty graph when I "save as" with Plotly in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

I'm new using plot.ly in python. I want to save from python multiples bubble graphs. When I'm trying to save my graph, this is empty, it has only the axis data, but the content (the main data) is empty in the graph (not in the variable).

I'm using the same method that in other graphs which are working well.

The way how I save the image is:

```
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
#plot_url = py.plot(fig)
py.image.save_as(fig, './images/upsdowns_'+str(individual_data['id'])+'.png')
```

The complete code is:

```
for individual_data in individual:

arrayData = []
particular_point = False
for points in arrayPoints:

    trace = Scatter(
        x = points['down'],
        y = points['up'],
        mode = 'markers',
        name = 'name',
        text = ['text'],
        marker = Marker(
            color='rgba(40, 120, 200, 0.5)',
            size = points['total'] * 10
        )
    )
    arrayData.append(trace)

    if points['up'] == individual_data['pups'] and not particular_point:
        trace2 = Scatter(
                x = points['down'],
                y = points['up'],
                mode = 'markers',
                name = 'name',
                text = ['text'],
                marker = Marker(
                    color='rgba(200, 120, 40, 0.5)',
                    size = 10
                )
        )
        arrayData.append(trace2)
        particular_point = True


data = Data(arrayData)

layout = Layout(
    title='Total Users Choice',
    titlefont=Font(
        family='',
        size=20,
        color=''
    ),
    font=Font(
        family='"PT Sans Narrow", sans-serif',
        size=14,
        color='#000'
    ),
    showlegend=False,
    autosize=False,
    width=600,
    height=500,
    xaxis=XAxis(
        title='Down',
        titlefont=Font(
            family='',
            size=0,
            color=''
        ),
        range=[0, 100],
        domain=[0, 1],
        type='linear',
        rangemode='normal',
        autorange=False,
        showgrid=True,
        zeroline=False,
        showline=False,
        autotick=True,
        nticks=12,
        ticks='',
        showticklabels=True,
        tick0=0,
        dtick=1,
        ticklen=5,
        tickwidth=1,
        tickcolor='#000',
        tickangle='auto',
        tickfont=Font(
            family='',
            size=0,
            color=''
        ),
        exponentformat='e',
        showexponent='all',
        mirror='all',
        gridcolor='#ddd',
        gridwidth=1,
        zerolinecolor='#000',
        zerolinewidth=1,
        linecolor='white',
        linewidth=1,
        anchor='y',
        overlaying=False,
        position=0
    ),
    yaxis=YAxis(
        title='Up',
        titlefont=Font(
            family='',
            size=0,
            color=''
        ),
        range=[0, 100],
        domain=[0, 1],
        type='linear',
        rangemode='normal',
        showgrid=True,
        zeroline=False,
        showline=False,
        autotick=True,
        nticks=12,
        ticks='',
        showticklabels=True,
        tick0=0,
        dtick=100,
        ticklen=5,
        tickwidth=1,
        tickcolor='#000',
        tickangle='auto',
        tickfont=Font(
            family='',
            size=0,
            color=''
        ),
        exponentformat='e',
        showexponent='all',
        mirror='all',
        gridcolor='#ddd',
        gridwidth=1,
        zerolinecolor='#000',
        zerolinewidth=1,
        linecolor='white',
        linewidth=1,
        anchor='x',
        overlaying=False,
        position=0
    ),
    legend=Legend(
        traceorder='normal',
        font=Font(
            family='',
            size=0,
            color=''
        ),
        bgcolor='#fff',
        bordercolor='#000',
        borderwidth=1
    ),
    margin=Margin(
        l=80,
        r=80,
        b=80,
        t=100,
        pad=2
    ),
    paper_bgcolor='rgb(245, 245, 245)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgb(245, 245, 245)',
    hovermode='closest',
    dragmode='zoom',
    separators='.,',
    barmode='stack',
    bargap=0.2,
    bargroupgap=0,
    boxmode='overlay',
    boxgap=0.3,
    boxgroupgap=0.3
)
fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
#plot_url = py.plot(fig)
py.image.save_as(fig, './images/upsdowns_'+str(individual_data['id'])+'.png')
```

Comment: Hm.. hard to know what is going wrong here, especially without seeing the original data. The call signature is OK. Could you share the `plot_url`? Alternatively, email me for support: chris@plot.ly

Comment: This is the url https://plot.ly/~julianvicens/174/total-users-choice/. My problem is when I'm trying to save the graph from python automatically. Thanks!!!

Comment: It looks like `x` and `y` aren't lists, just single floats. If you change the `x` and `y` assignments to e.g. `x = [points['down']]` and `y = [points['up']]` then that should work.

Comment: Fixed! Thanks Chris!